# ¿Hay diferentes palabras para el hermano de una esposa, y el esposo de una hermana?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, definiciones, parentesco

Sé que la traduccion de la frase “brother-in-law“ es “cuñado“. ¿“Cuñado" se refiere al hermano de una esposa, el esposo de una hermana, o los dos?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Del [diccionario de la RAE](http://www.rae.es/drae/)

> cuñado, da.
>   (Del lat. cognātus).
>   1. m. y f. Hermano del cónyuge.
>   2. m. y f. Cónyuge del hermano.
>   3. m. y f. concuñado (‖ cónyuge de alguien respecto del cónyuge de otra persona hermana de aquel).
>   4. m. y f. Am. U. como fórmula de tratamiento afectivo para dirigirse a los amigos.
>   5. m. y f. ant. Pariente por afinidad, en cualquier grado.

Por tanto, viendo las acepciones 1 y 2, se refiere a ambos.

Comment: Yo añadiría también que, en muchas jurisdicciones, también se refiere al hermano de un esposo y al esposo de un hermano ;-)

Comment: @Chewie _"Cónyuge"_ es suficientemente general. Aunque realmente dudo que esa haya sido la intención de la RAE

Comment: Me refería a la formulación de la pregunta de Peter, que excluye los otros casos.

Comment: @Chewie Y lo mío era una broma :)