# ¿Hay o hubo palabras para diferenciar las dos primeras acepciones de "cuñado"?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, historia, sustantivos

En *[¿Hay diferentes palabras para el hermano de una esposa, y el esposo de una hermana?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/3105/12637)* parece que se preguntó esto mismo, pero al final se preguntó a qué se refería exactamente la palabra *[cuñado](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Bh3HRKG)*. Viendo las dos primeras acepciones me resulta curioso que dos parentescos en principio diferenciados usen la misma palabra:

> 1. m. y f. Hermano del cónyuge de una persona.
>
> 2. m. y f. Cónyuge del hermano de una persona.

Así que retomo la pregunta original y amplío: ¿Existen o han existido palabras que diferencien estas dos acepciones de "cuñado"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No creo, y en caso de que haya existido, sería hace mucho, porque ya en el diccionario de Covarrubias se recogen las dos acepciones en el artículo **cuñado**:

> Es el hermano del marido, respeto de la muger; y el hermano de la muger, respeto del marido..... Cuñado, el marido de la hermana, y cuñada la muger del hermano.

Por otro lado, en el diccionario de Corominas se recoge que

> "Cuñado era antiguamente 'pariente político' en general ...  que en la baja época significa 'pariente de cualquier clase' y luego especializó progresivamente su significado. A finales del S. XIII  la *Primera Crónica General* emplea todavía *cuñado* en el sentido de 'pariente por afinidad', pero ya la Crónica de 1344 tiende a evitar el vocablo, seguramente por la tendencia a especializarlo en el sentido moderno..."

Comment: Definitivamente creo que voy a pedir el etimológico de Corominas para mi próximo cumpleaños...